# Remove attributes "height" and "width" of the image tag

Tags: html, content-management-system, typo3, responsive-design, typoscript

In order to create a responsive website with [Typo3](http://www.typo3.org) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), I would like to remove the *height* and *width* attributs of images

Here's how images are generated in Frontend via content element of type *text & image* and *image*

```
<img src="typo3temp/pics/a625b79f89.jpg" width="300" height="226" alt="blabla" />
```

I would like to remove the dimension attributes and get this:

```
<img src="typo3temp/pics/a625b79f89.jpg" alt="blaba" />
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: if jquery is fine with you, then please see this http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to remove the height or width image attributes with typoscript.

But you could override it with CSS in order to create a responsive website.

`img {
        height:100% !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }`

Comment: I have come across the same issue in order to keep original size of the new image the width & height of old attributes to be removed jquery way is [here][1] 

by setting 100% !important in css you are telling browser to set the img size 100% relative to its parent irrespective of its original size which I guess is not the right way to do


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeattr.asp

Answer (score 10):

Call an image tag in document.ready function.

```
$('img').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
```

Comment: With Bootstrap you may want to also add the `img-responsive` class to the images at the same time.  `$('img').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height').addClass('img-responsive');`

Answer (score 6):

FYI: There is no way to remove this with typoscript. The `width` and `height` attribute is hardcoded in `sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_content.php` function `cImage`. (Typo3 4.7)

Comment: A pity that it takes developers so long to get rid of web 1.0 habits.

Answer (score 5):

Use jquery

set an id to your image object:

```
<img src="typo3temp/pics/a625b79f89.jpg" width="300" height="226" alt="blabla" id="myimage" />

$('#myimage').removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width");
```

here is alternative javascript code:

```
var myImage= document.getElementById("myimage");
myImage.removeAttribute("heigth");
myImage.removeAttribute("width");
```

Comment: I would have preferred a solution via typoscript. But I will test it in jQuery.
I had not thought of jQuery. I will test it.

Comment: i suggested to use jquery , wont be sorry

Answer (score 3):

This will be possible with TYPO3 6.2 LTS. Checkout http://forge.typo3.org/issues/49723.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the effects of fixed width and/or height attributes without actually removing these attributes you can set them back to "auto" in your CSS definitions:

```
img {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

I suggest to do that only for the img tags where you really need the pictures to be fluid. This could be done by adding an id or class to the img tags or any surrounding tag.

E.g. if your fluid images are located in a wrapper div with class "fluid_pics" you could use:

```
.fluid_pics img {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Often you will only need to set the height back to auto, as the width is already overwritten to be 100% by your framework (e.g. Twitter Bootstrap).

Comment: In my opinion this is the best approach. No javascript required, and things like auto-scaling in combination with max-width still work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TypoScript to Remove "width" and "height" attributes from the source code.  TYPO3 CMS 6.1+.

```
tt_content.image.20.stdWrap.parseFunc.nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.img.fixAttrib {
width.unset = 1
height.unset = 1
border.unset = 1
}

tt_content.textpic.20.stdWrap.parseFunc.nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.img.fixAttrib {
width.unset = 1
height.unset = 1
border.unset = 1
}

lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.img.fixAttrib {
width.unset = 1
height.unset = 1
border.unset = 1
}
```

tt_news example:
News List

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList.image.stdWrap.parseFunc.nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.img.fixAttrib {
width.unset = 1
height.unset = 1
border.unset = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your image has an `id` or another unique attribute assigned, you can easily do this:

```
var myImg=document.getElementById('myImage');
myImg && myImg.removeAttribute('height') && myImg.removeAttribute('width');
```

Answer (score 1):

For Typo3 6.2 upwards you may set a custom image render layout
(snippet belongs to TS setup):

```
tt_content.image.20.1 {
    layout {
        mylayout {
            # equals default rendering, except width and height removed
            element = <img src="###SRC###" ###PARAMS### ###ALTPARAMS### ###BORDER### ###SELFCLOSINGTAGSLASH###>
        }
    }
}
```

Enable the custom layout for css_styled_content (snippet belongs to TS constants):

```
styles.content.imgtext.layoutKey = mylayout
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html#cobj-image-layoutkey
for details on the IMAGE cObject.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work with T3 7.6 - do both scripts go in the SETUP section of my template?

Comment: @uTILLIty I edited the answer with hints, where the snippets have to be placed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a VERY simple solution with jQuery.  i found the answer at wpwizard.net.

Here's the URL:
http://wpwizard.net/jquery/remove-img-height-and-width-with-jquery/

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('img').each(function(){ 
        $(this).removeAttr('width')
        $(this).removeAttr('height');
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for old TYPO3s with TYPOSCRIPT:

```
stdWrap {
    replacement {
        10 {
            search = /\s+(width|height)="[^"]+"/
            useRegExp = 1
            replace =
        }
    }
}
```

Use this stdWrap-TS where your image is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

it dont work in 6.1 :/
but u can use CSS:

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```