# Remove default size attribute of featured svg img in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, svg

I tried to upload svg file for featured image of one post, but it failed to show. Below are what I saw in dev tool.

```
<img width="1" height="1" src=".../featured.svg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="featured" oldsrc=".../featured.svg">
```

It seemed that it generated `width="1" height="1"` for featured image. Is there any way to change the default setting? I prefer to change the code instead of using JavaScript to remove the attributes.

Comment: Does this happen for Every Post Image or a particular Image ? OR a particular Image gets a width&height automatically ?

Comment: Please refer this [**SOque**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014165/remove-attributes-height-and-width-of-the-image-tag), that will do the trick for you.

Comment: @Vinayak Every svg in every post, and both featured and images in post are.

Answer (score 1):

You can give Height and Withd 100% for your every Post Thumbnail Images :

e.g :

```
.post img {
    height:100% !important; /* add !important */
    width:100% !important; /* add !important */
}
```

Comment: That's the `style` attribute, not for `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: It will apply the width height to the image. Try it.